# ASP.net dangerous submission error

Tags: c#, asp.net, yetanotherforum

When I  try and run a forum page:

```
System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client
```

In my web.config I have:

```
<pages validateRequest="false" smartNavigation="false">
```

And on the actual page I  also have:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" ValidateRequest="false" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/Main.master" %>
```

But it keeps throwing this error!

### Edit

I fixed it with:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

But what's that do and why does it work?

Comment: What version of ASP.NET are you using?

Comment: It changed how strict ASP.Net checks the requests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error occurs because something in the submitted form, or in the querystring, looked dangerous to the validation in ASP.NET.

By adding

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

you are relaxing the validation that is applied back to the standards of ASP.NET 2.

I would say you are far better off trying to work out exactly what it objects to in your form/querystring than just relaxing the validation. This tightened validation is there to protect you and your users, and shouldn't be relaxed lightly.

I have recently hit this on a project I am working on when we upgraded to ASP.NET MVC3 (from version 2). In our case it actually highlighted an issue whereby we were urlencoding our querystring when we didn't mean to (i.e. the entire quertstring including the question mark and the ampersands was all getting url encoded when it shouldn't be).

Whatever your reason, look for the root cause rather than relax the validation if it is at all possible.

Answer (score 5):

There was probably markup in the submitted text. http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes

> The request validation feature in
>   ASP.NET provides a certain level of
>   default protection against cross-site
>   scripting (XSS) attacks. In previous
>   versions of ASP.NET, request
>   validation was enabled by default.
>   However, it applied only to ASP.NET
>   pages (.aspx files and their class
>   files) and only when those pages were
>   executing.
>
> In ASP.NET 4, by default, request
>   validation is enabled for all
>   requests, because it is enabled before
>   the BeginRequest phase of an HTTP
>   request. As a result, request
>   validation applies to requests for all
>   ASP.NET resources, not just .aspx page
>   requests. This includes requests such
>   as Web service calls and custom HTTP
>   handlers. Request validation is also
>   active when custom HTTP modules are
>   reading the contents of an HTTP
>   request.
>
> As a result, request validation errors
>   might now occur for requests that
>   previously did not trigger errors. To
>   revert to the behavior of the ASP.NET
>   2.0 request validation feature, add the following setting in the
>   Web.config file:
>
> ```
> <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
> ```